# invalid byte sequence for encoding "UTF8": 0x95-while using PGP Encryption -PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I was working on Asymmetric encryption in postgres using pgcrypto . I have generated the keys and stored in data folder and had  inserted the data using pgcrypto encrypt function .

here the problem comes, I was trying to decrypt the data but it was throwing me the below error

ERROR:  invalid byte sequence for encoding "UTF8": 0x95

Please find the below process which I followed

Generated the keys :
CREATE EXTENSION pgcrypto;

$ gpg --list-keys

### /home/ec2-user/.gnupg/pubring.gpg

pub   2048R/8GGGFF 2020-03-19
uid       [ultimate] postgres
sub   2048R/GGGFF7 2020-03-19

create table users(username varchar(100),id integer,ssn bytea);

postgres=# INSERT INTO users VALUES('randomname',7,pgp_pub_encrypt('434-88-8880',dearmor(pg_read_file('keys/public.key'))));

INSERT 0 1

postgres=# SELECT pgp_pub_decrypt(ssn,dearmor(pg_read_file('keys/private.key'))) AS mydata FROM users;

ERROR:  invalid byte sequence for encoding "UTF8": 0x95

postgres=# show client_encoding;

### client_encoding

UTF8
(1 row)

postgres=# show server_encoding;

### server_encoding

UTF8
(1 row)

Can anyone please help me to solve this  .

Comment: It works for me, I get back '434-88-8880'.  What version of postgresql are you using?  How did you generate the keys?

Comment: I am using  9.6 version . I generated keys using gpg tool.

Comment: I worked for me on 9.6 as well.  I meant specifically what did you do in gpg?  I don't think a bad key format or something would give the error you show, but I don't see any other options to explain it either.

Comment: Sorry for late response. I tried in different version (9.2) it worked for me as well . But may be I have done something wrong which generating keys in 9.6 version. I need to re run the process and see what I have done wrong .